# How can I change code this to a switch statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

EDIT: Here is the code for the toppings. I'm not sure how to print the names out in the case that more than one topping is selected.

```
    public double getToppingCost()
    {

        double toppingCost = 0.0;


        if (creamCheese.isSelected())
            toppingCost += CREAM_CHEESE;
        if (butter.isSelected())
            toppingCost += BUTTER;
        if (peachJelly.isSelected())
            toppingCost += PEACH_JELLY;
        if (blueberryJam.isSelected())
            toppingCost += BLUEBERRY_JAM;
        if (nutella.isSelected())
            toppingCost += NUTELLA;


        return toppingCost;
    }
```

Comment: Since you're checking boolean values, if statements seem appropriate. Switches are used with variables that can take on many different values. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change this to a switch statement in a straighforward manner.  Switch examines a single variable and provides separate case branches based on the value of that single variable, as well as a possible default branch if none of the conditions match.

*In your case, your logic depends on the state of multiple variables, not of a single variable.*

You could force this into a switch semantic e.g. by defining a new variable and setting its value based on whiteBagel.isSelected() and then wheatBagel.isSelected(), and then writing a switch based on that new variable.  However, this would only add complexity and reduce readability of the code.

**UPDATE**

The way you have edited the question, this is even less a match for a *switch* statement.

Comment: Is there possibly a different way to write it? Not necessarily a switch statement, just any way other than if statements?

Comment: The way you have written it is very common.  Note however that you miss the combination that both the white bagel and the wheat bagel have been selected (I'm not sure if that is actually possible in your code).

Comment: This update to the question pretty significantly changes what you were asking.  Rather than eliminate the original context, it would be better to add on to the question (e.g. "What if my if..else looked like this instead?"), or to ask a new question.

Comment: This is a new question entirely, should I mark this one as answered and re ask this question?